# AngularJS website with user logins

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to make a website where people can register and log in, but if I'm right. Everytime the user refeshes the page he will be logged out? How do I prevent that?

For example:

> User logged in ➞ does his stuff on the website ➞ refreshes the page ➞ is logged out

Comment: By persisting a login session on the server.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to use PHP?

Comment: Not specifically PHP - you just need some kind of server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a short answer to broad topic, but to answer your questions:

First of all, you would need some kind of authentication service on the back-end to verify the user. On successful login it would return `HTTP 200` and the user information:

```
{
  "user":{
    "firstname": "MyFirstname"
    "lastname": "MyLastname"
  } 
}
```

The user information (and probably some sort of token or session-id), will be stored client-side. This will keep the data persisted (even if the browser window is closed) and you will always have access to it from the rest of your application.

```
angular.module('app').factory('AuthenticationService', function() {
  // call the back-end login service
  // handle login, logout, authentication and authorization 
  // storing the userinfo in localstorage, cookie etc.
});
```